# Civilians stuck on a roof

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The Aliens were invading Montreal, so I sent a strike force to intercept them. I came across a bunch of civilians holed up in what appears to be a library. After murdering about a dozen of the alien scum, at the cost of about half a dozen civilians, I've rescued all but three that are hiding on the roof... somehow. I can't find any way to access them, is there an item I'm missing like a jetpack or grappling hook that allows me to get up there? Do I have to abandon them? Or was I supposed to let them be killed by the Floaters that spawned nearby?

Comment: Those aren't aliens, that's just what people from Montreal look like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've killed all the aliens, any remaining civilians will be considered "rescued". On the roof is probably a pretty safe place for civilians to be, so you might just be able to ignore them and clear out the rest of the xenos.

Otherwise, if you really need to get up there, look for a drainpipe or ladder on an outside wall, or a staircase to the roof from inside. Your operatives can climb these to get to higher ground. Civilians will never spawn in a place that operatives can't get to, so there must be a way up there somewhere.

Comment: Is it possible to blow up ladders/drainpipes?

Comment: @DanNeely Honestly, I've never tried it! I don't use rockets or grenades that much, so I have no idea. Probably, though, so maybe Sconibulus has accidentally done so.

Comment: @DanNeely Yes, it is. I one killed a cyberdisk that blew up, taking out the wall... and the ladder.

Answer (score 6):

There is a grappling hook (on the Skeleton Suit and Ghost Armor) and a jetpack (on the Archangel Armor), but you won't ever be required to have them to complete a mission.

Usually, if you move your soldiers around the outside of a building, you'll see in their move radius the methods by which they can get up to the next level.  There are also occasionally routes through the interior of a building up to higher ground.